# Numbering duplicates record in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

I have Student table and I want to update (sequence_No.) field like that:

```
ID        Name      age     sequence_No.
--        -----     ---     ------------

1         sara      20         1

2         sara      20         2

3         sara      20         3

4         john      24         1

5         john      24         2

6         Hama      23         1
```

Which query can do that in mysql?

thank you :)

Comment: you want to generate column like sequence_no , right ?

Comment: yes , if it's possible

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT 
ID,
Name,
age,
( 
CASE Name 
WHEN @curType 
THEN @curRow := @curRow + 1 
ELSE @curRow := 1 AND @curType := Name END
) + 1 AS sequence_No

FROM student, (SELECT @curRow := 0, @curType := '') r
ORDER BY  ID,NAME;
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3e6b6d/5)**

Comment: @hama I am glad it helped you. Welcome to SO.

Answer (score 3):

hope this will help you :

```
SELECT *, count(*) as seq_number FROM student a
JOIN student b ON a.name = b.name AND a.id >= b.id
GROUP BY a.id
```

[Sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/7c08f/4)

Comment: this is also worked , but it need more time to execute , thanks

Answer (score 1):

try out this..

```
select ID,Name,age,sequence_No 
from Student having count(Name) > 1 
order by Name asc
```

Comment: thanks, it doesn't work , I want to update sequence_No. field to numbering duplicate record